# How do I retrieve the preferences from my settings activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, settings, preferences

I am currently struggling with Kotlin for my Bachelor thesis and I have no idea what I am doing.

So here is my problem:

I created a (functional) settings activity with multiple EditTextPreferences and a ListPreference.
Right now I want to retrieve the selected item from the ListPreference in another activity.
This is my ListPreference:

```
    <ListPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Art des Implantates"
        android:entries="@array/settings_list_preference_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/settings_list_preference_values"
        android:key="list"
        android:title="Implantat"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"/>
```

So how do I retrieve the selected Item? Let's say I just want to display it somewhere else. I have no clue whatsoever, since every single Tutorial I came across is for java and I don't speak java.

Please help me. I'm desperate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step #1: Get a `SharedPreferences` object for the default preferences:

```
val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

(where `context` is a `Context`, such as an `Activity` or the `Application` singleton)

Step #2: Call `getString("list", someDefaultValue)` on the `SharedPreferences`, where `"list"` is your key (from your `<ListPreference>`) and `someDefaultValue` is a `String` that you want returned if the user has not yet set this preference

> since every single Tutorial I came across is for java

[This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.8/SimplePrefs) (from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack)) is in Kotlin and shows the use of `SharedPreferences`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) also shows the use of `SharedPreferences` with Kotlin (and Java).

Comment: Thank you! Now it worked. That was all the information I needed and it still took me all day to figure it out :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

You can access values by using XML app:key="this_value" like this:

```
prefs.getString("this_value","some_val");
```